# Defining lists in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell

I'd like to know how to define this as a list within Haskell so that I could perform operations such as tail, reverse and length:

```
cars = "lamborghinis are my favourite types of car"
```

I've tried:

```
let cars = [lamborghinis,are,my,favourite,types,of,car]
let cars = ["lamborghinis","are","my","favourite","types","of","car"]
let cars = ['lamborghinis','are','my','favourite','types','of','car']
```

I have been using http://learnyouahaskell.com/starting-out as a tutorial as I am new to Haskell and I can't see where I'm going wrong, I thought my first attempt above would be correct as that it how it does it in the tutorial but with numbers instead of words.

The error I am getting is: `parse error on input 'of`.

Any ideas where I'm going wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Strings are already lists, i.e. String is a type synonym for [Char]. For example, "hello" and ['h','e','l','l','o'] are the same things. What is it that you want to do exactly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
let cars = "lamborghinis are my favourite types of car"
```

makes cars a list of characters `[Char]==String` and `head cars` should give you the first letter. This is special syntax of haskell for strings

```
let cars2 = ["lamborghinis","are","my","favourite","types","of","car"]
```

This is the normal form for defining lists and gives you a list of strings `[String]` and `head cars` should give you `"lamborghinis"`.
You can also split a sentance into words using the words function.

```
let cars3 = words cars
```

Answer (score 1):

The type `String` is only a *type synonym* for `[Char]`.

This means that for example `"Hello, you"` is the same as `['H','e','l','l','o',',',' ','y','o','u']`